# Do Origin Cloud saves work properly with Steam?

Tags: steam, origin

I have Origin and Battlefield 3 and prefer to launch BF3 via Steam. The game runs fine, but when I launch Origin occasionally gives a warning that Cloud Saves can only be used when launching via Origin.

I'm not sure what this is supposed to mean; launching via Steam still opens/authenticates via Origin and takes me to the Battlelog website, the game works fine and it runs the Cloud Save sync before stating the game. However I've noticed that it seems to occasionally cause sync conflicts when starting the game.

If I play Origin games via Steam, is it not uploading my Cloud Save files to Origin or what? I only have one PC, so conflicts aren't a huge problem, but *do* want my files backed up in the cloud. Origin is of course installed, so if necessary I can just launch BF3 through that.

Comment: Wasn't sure if I should add the Battlefield 3 tag to this; no idea if it's unique to this game, I assume not but it's my only game on Origin (and hopefully will remain that way).

Comment: It seems that what Origin means is that your saves won't be uploaded to the cloud, or updated from it. I made sure that I would never use Origin, so don't have it on PC, but this seems to be the problem.

Comment: @Dimtuhop The uploads seem to work sometimes though, it's like after the failed start *then* it uploads.

Answer (score 2):

I also start Battlefield 3 through Steam, so that I have the overlay and friends can see what I'm playing. I never had the issues you're reporting here.

But: How do you start Battlefield 3 from Steam? The shortcut I created links to the Origin.exe, otherwise it didn't work for me. Maybe you link to the battlefield3.exe?

If yes, try linking it to Origin, I've never had problems this way.

Comment: I guess that's the problem; yeah I link directly to bf3.exe. Was hoping I could get at it without launching two launchers just to get to the game ><